# Reduction to separable ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is find the particular solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}$=$\frac{y-x}{y+x}$ when f(7)=7

For $\frac{dy}{dx}$=$\frac{y-x}{y+x}$,
first i substitute y and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to
$ux$ and $x\frac{du}{dx}+u$ so the equation change to

$x\frac{du}{dx}+u$=$\frac{u-1}{u+1}$
now i think this equation is separable.
$(u+1)du$=$\frac{-2}{x}dx$
Then I integration the equation and solve the problem but I wrong
I think i solve the problem right way and I can't find my mistake what is the wrong part of my solution?

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is that 
$$
\frac{u-1}{u+1}-u=-\frac{1+u^2}{1+u}.
$$
So the new equation is 
$$
\frac{1+u}{1+u^2}\,u'=-\frac1x.
$$
So you get 
$$
\arctan u + \frac12\,\log (1+u^2)=-\log x + c,
$$
which gives you 
$$
\arctan \frac yx+\frac12\,\log(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2})=-\log x + c.
$$
No hope of solving this explicitly. Since $y(7)=7$, $$c=\arctan 1+\frac 12\log2+\log7=\frac\pi4+\log(7\sqrt2).$$

Comment: We can also use $y(7)=7$ to determine $c = \pi/4 + \log(7\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks.